# Personal/Group messaging schema

Tags: mysql, message

How to create message conversation schema in MySQL both personal group messaging. Is there a possibility to create with following scenario.

1. read/unread
2. If user delete conversation does not affect other.(For example user A & B has message conversation A clears Message then B messages should not affect)

Comment: How to create messaging schema?

Comment: Just like facebook message schema... that's it.. :)

Comment: what is wrong with what Horia is working up below ?

Comment: Yes he did good... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
MessageGroup (
    ID, 
    GroupName
)

Message (
    ID, 
    Text, 
    MessageGroupId (FK TO MessageGroup(ID))
)

User (
    ID, 
    UserName
)

UserMessage (
    ID, 
    MessageID (FK to Message(ID)), 
    UserID (FK to User(ID), 
    Cleared (true/false)
)
```

This way, each user can clear the message but only for him, while others can still have their messages unaffected.

Comment: Seems like a lot of inserting into tables when a message is created? Can you further explain how it'll be implemented?

Comment: For just a simple message creation you require 2 steps. 1 - insert the actual message / 2 - assign the message to the users you want. Hope it helps